# AWS Windows Server 2012R2 AMI + UserData Run

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, packer

My packer script is as follows:

```
{
    "description": "APLP GOLD IMAGE {{isotime \"20060102\"}}",
    "min_packer_version": "0.11.0",
    "variables": {
        "aws_region": "us-east-2",
        "aws_vpc": "xxxxxx",
        "aws_subnet": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "builders": [
        {
            "type": "amazon-ebs",
            "profile": "nonprod",
            "ami_name": "APLP (encrypted) {{isotime \"20060102\"}}",
            "ami_description": "APLP Server2012R2 x86_64 HVM EBS (encrypted) {{isotime \"20060102\"}}",
            "instance_type": "t2.micro",
            "region": "{{user `aws_region`}}",
            "vpc_id": "{{user `aws_vpc`}}",
            "subnet_id": "{{user `aws_subnet`}}",
             "source_ami_filter": {
                "filters": {
                    "name": "Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-Base-*",
                    "virtualization-type": "hvm"
                },
                "owners": ["801119661308"],
                "most_recent": true
            },
            "communicator": "winrm",
            "user_data_file":"./SetUpWinRM.ps1",
            "winrm_username": "Administrator",
            "winrm_use_ssl": true,
            "winrm_insecure": true,
            "ami_virtualization_type": "hvm",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "APLP Server2012R2 Gold",
                "OS": "Windows Server",
                "OSVER": "2012R2"
            },
            "encrypt_boot": true,
            "launch_block_device_mappings": [
                {
                  "device_name": "/dev/sda1",
                  "volume_size": 100,
                  "volume_type": "gp2",
                  "delete_on_termination": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "powershell",
            "scripts": [
                "sysprep.ps1",
                "ec2config.ps1",
                "defrag.ps1",
                "disableuac.ps1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My user data inside the build just configures WINRM which has been shown several places online and that works great.  I have also several powershell provisoner tasks that run, on in particular that runs:

```
$EC2SettingsFile = "C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\Ec2ConfigService\\Settings\\Config.xml"
$xml = [xml](get-content $EC2SettingsFile)
$xmlElement = $xml.get_DocumentElement()
$xmlElementToModify = $xmlElement.Plugins
foreach ($element in
    $xmlElementToModify.Plugin) {
    if ($element.name -eq
        "Ec2SetPassword") {
        $element.State = "Enabled"
    }
    elseif ($element.name -eq
        "Ec2SetComputerName") {
        $element.State = "Enabled"
    }
    elseif ($element.name -eq
        "Ec2HandleUserData") {
        $element.State = "Enabled"
    }
    elseif ($element.name -eq
        "Ec2DynamicBootVolumeSize") {
        $element.State = "Enabled"
    }
}
$xml.Save($EC2SettingsFile)
```

After image creation, I've even created a volume from the snapshot to ensure that the Config.xml is currently configured to run userdata.  The problem I'm having is that the userdata never runs that gets tied to the new instance I build using my AMI from packer.  If I use a AWS clean AMI my userdata runs fine, when I run the same user data using my custom AMI it doesn't.

my understanding is that the reason I'm making changes to the config.xml in the configservice is so that userdata does run one more time.  I can also pull up the ec2config UI inside windows after the AMI gets deployed, and click the run userdata upon boot and everything runs as expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I've got the same issue.